# When to use what types

Tags: vhdl

**Questions:**

1. Is there a more appropiate "supertype" to `signed` and `unsigned` than `std_logic_vector` (regarding my case)?
2. Is it ok to define an Input as (subtype of) Integer or is it better to define it as bitvector? (Are there any Issues with the Integer approach)
3. When should I use resolved or unresolved logic for the Inputs/Outputs off an Entity?

   - Resolved for Bus drivers (because of the "high Z drivers") otherwise unresolved?
   - Always resolved so a bus can be driven/used as input (this seems wrong, because when would I use unresolved then?)

**Actual Case:**

I am declaring an entity and am wondering for the right types for the inputs and outputs.
Lets assume I am constructing a dynamic width equal. It compares the first n Bits of two Inputs for equality.

The entity definition would be:

```
entity comparisonDynWidth is
    generic(
        width       : positive;
        min_width   : positive;
            -- when the tools suport vhdl2008 enough
            -- reason for both signed/unsigned => std_logic inputs
        --function compareFunc (x: in std_logic_vector; y: in std_logic_vector)  return std_logic 
    );
    port (
        left, right : in  std_logic_vector(width-1 downto 0);
        widthControl: in  natural range 0 to width-min_width;
        result      : out std_logic / std_ulogic ??
    );
```

I chose std_logic_vector as Input since I want it to look the ports like a generic `less than` comparator as well, for which signedness matters and which can have `signed` and `unsigned` inputs.
since it is easier for me to define the width as an integer I did so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a more appropiate "supertype" to signed and unsigned than
>   std_logic_vector (regarding my case)?

Not sure what you mean, but you have no choice - `signed` and `unsigned` are defined in the standard.

> Is it ok to define an Input as (subtype of) Integer or is it better to
>   define it as bitvector? (Are there any Issues with the Integer
>   approach)

Integers will flag errors if you go outside their range.  vectors (`signed` and `unsigned`) will wrap around.  Which is "correct" depends on what you want and how you feel about coding explicit wrap-around if you want it with integers.

> When should I use resolved or unresolved logic for the Inputs/Outputs
>   off an Entity?

If you stick to:

- only using resolved types for the top level IO ports (i.e. the actual pins of the device)
- using unresolved types internally

you will be able catch errors involving multiple drivers on a signal with a detailed error-message at elaboration-time.  This can be preferable to chasing down `X`s in your waveforms at simulation-time.

There are no internal tri-state buses internally to most technologies these days, so you can't have multiple drivers, so there's no need for resolved signals inside the device.  IO pins (almost?) always have tri-stateble drivers, so the use of a resolved type is appropriate, and the driving of a 'Z' can be used to infer that behaviour.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the awnser to the third part of the question, lets assume I want to implement open drain, are you telling me this is not possible in most technologies? How do I implement a bus if I can't Tristate the drivers and if I can I do need resolved logic correct?

Comment: If you want open-drain, then that is going to be on a top-level IO port, and using a resolved type is quite alright and expected there.

Answer (score 1):

1. std_logic_vector is a good choice in your case (and in most cases in an entity, as it represents hardware situation best... e.g. with use of 'U' and 'Z' and so on)
2. the use of integer in an entity is ok as long as it is not the top-level entity. in top level entities, the exclusive use of std_logic(_vector) is recommended.
3. most tools report multi-driver situations anyway... the use of resolved types is therefore ok.

Comment: 1. In what way does 'U' represent hardware?  and 3. Most simulators don't report multiple drivers, they just simulate what you wrote.  Synthesisers do report it (amongst a million other messages), but I usually spend much more time simulating than synthesising, so it's a bit late by then :)

Comment: 'U' is undefined and means, that the signal is not driven... unfortunately not everything in hardware is defined as '0' or '1' ;-)

Comment: I basically agree with you on (3). however, running synthesis every now and then even during your simulation process is recommended anyway... e.g. to get rid of the millions of warnings early ;-)